# vb.net problem System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, Hey I have problem where this error pop out

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Im coding with vb and this error pops out which im lack the understanding of
[image]

-This is my coding

```
Public Overloads Overridable Function Fill(ByVal dataTable As SarahShortCake_CaseStudyDataSet.SalesInfoDataTable) As Integer
            Me.Adapter.SelectCommand = Me.CommandCollection(0)
            If (Me.ClearBeforeFill = true) Then
                dataTable.Clear
            End If
            Dim returnValue As Integer = Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)
            Return returnValue
        End Function
```

Comment: help im just a student trying to survive

Comment: Please add all information to your question in text form. Also, please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: noted will do thx

Comment: is there a way for me to communicate with you cuz its quite hard for to explain it here, thank you

Comment: @JohnWeck By explaining the problem you too will understand it better, in some cases you will even find a solution: maybe if it's so hard for you to explain it you didn't even understood it too well, and that's one more reason to try and explain it

Comment: So, I can just about read all the exception helper.. That's not your coding; pretty sure visual studio wrote that code :) but suffice to say that you seem to have a datetimepicker somewhere that is bound to a table row where there is a date that is being set to datetime.minvalue, and that's an earlier date than the datetimepicker's minvalue setting, so it's throwing an error